# How do I create and save an object with initialized has_many of another model object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a Challenge object with a has_many relationship with :weeks.

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :weeks
end
```

In my create method I want to initialize 12 empty Week objects and put them on the challenge.

Here is my create method currently. I got the basically outline for the following code from a sample rails 4 app. I don't fully understand why build takes the params.require

```
def create
  @challenge = current_user.challenges.build(params.require(:challenge).permit(:start_weight))
  if @challenge.save
    flash[:success] = "Challenge created!"
    redirect_to current_user
  end
end
```

My first instinct is to add something like this:

```
def create
  weeks = []
  12.times {weeks << Week.new}
  @challenge = current_user.challenges.build(challenge_params)
  @challenge.weeks = weeks
  if @challenge.save
    flash[:success] = "Challenge created!"
    redirect_to current_user
  end
end
```

I'm new to rails but I know this has got to be wrong.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!